# Cordova WP Silverlight 8.1 project change publisher display name

Tags: cordova, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

When I upload my .xap file to the Windows Developer App submission page, I get the following error:

```
Package acceptance validation error: The publisher display name, xxxx, specified in the package doesn’t match the publisher name, yyyy, that’s associated with the developer account.
```

How do I fix this? I changed the WMAppManifest.xml packaging section to reflect the author and publisher ID mentioned in the developer account profile but it still does gives the same error. My Visual Studio Community 2015 is also signed in with the same developer account.

Comment: Have you tried to publish the app with Visual Studio? There a a lot of questions like yours here on [SO], I guess going through them might help ;)

Comment: In Visual Studio, under the Store menu, I only get the Code Certification Kit option in my Silverlight project for Windows Phone 8.1.